# Difference between homoscedastic and homogenic-variance data

Tags: r, anova, variance

I have a doubt regarding two tests:

**Breusch–Pagan test**, to detect heteroscedasticity in a series, and 
**Bartlett's test**, to test for equal variances for samples from $k$
populations.

What are the difference betwen those two tests?

- Are not those tests highly related?
- How could a homoscedastic data give no homogeneity in the variance?

Comment: Did you google "homoscedasticity"? The first link, not surprisingly, is Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoscedasticity. You will find that "homoscedasticity" and "homogeneity of variance" are the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The aim of the [B-P test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breusch%E2%80%93Pagan_test) is to assess whether the residuals in a linear model have constant variance, by regressing the square of the residuals on the independent variables.  [Bartlett's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartlett%27s_test) seeks to determine whether multiple samples come from populations that all have the same variance.  You could view the latter as a special case of the former, in thinking of the linear model that corresponds to a one-way ANOVA, but the details of the test statistics are rather different.  I would agree that they are related, and that you could apply the former in the context in which the latter is generally used, with potentially different results.